# How to fix 500 error in Sitecore ribbon on first Experience Editor / Preview mode load

Tags: paas

Every time I deploy to the Azure App Service, the first load of preview or edit mode takes extremely long to load and when the page does become visible, a 500 error becomes visible where the Sitecore ribbon.

[image: 500 - The request timed out]

The Sitecore logs show the following:

```
2018-11-09T22:54:05  PID[1052] Error       11772 22:54:05 ERROR Failed to render rendering

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException

Message: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/PageEditbar/PageEditBar.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').

Source: Sitecore.Mvc

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

Nested Exception

Exception: System.ArgumentException

Message: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '{B11432AF-89DD-4F53-A1A5-2A9D1B2244E0}'  Key being added: '{B11432AF-89DD-4F53-A1A5-2A9D1B2244E0}'

Source: mscorlib

   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Web.Sprites.SpriteDefinitionManager..ctor(Database database, ID spriteStorageNodeId, ISpriteDefinitionFactory spriteDefinitionFactory, ICachedItemsWatcherFactory cachedItemsWatcherFactory)

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.PrepareEditorResources.Processors.RenderHiddenCachedImages.Process(PrepareEditorResourcesArgs args)

   at (Object , Object )

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.PrepareEditorResources.ExecutePrepareEditorResourcesPipeline.Run(PrepareEditorResourcesArgs args)

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.PageEditBar.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)

   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render()

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.ControlsExtension.PageEditBar(Controls controls, Rendering rendering, HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper)

   at ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_ExperienceEditor_PageEditbar_PageEditBar_cshtml.Execute() in d:\home\site\wwwroot\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\PageEditbar\PageEditBar.cshtml:line 4

   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()

   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()

   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)







2018-11-09T22:54:05  PID[1052] Error       11772 22:54:05 ERROR Failed to render rendering

Exception: System.InvalidOperationException

Message: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-Layout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').



Source: Sitecore.Mvc

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)



Nested Exception



Exception: System.InvalidOperationException

Message: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/PageEditbar/PageEditBar.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').



Source: Sitecore.Mvc

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)

   at (Object , Object )

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)

   at (Object , Object )

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)

   at ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml.Execute()

   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()

   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()

   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)



Nested Exception



Exception: System.ArgumentException

Message: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '{B11432AF-89DD-4F53-A1A5-2A9D1B2244E0}'  Key being added: '{B11432AF-89DD-4F53-A1A5-2A9D1B2244E0}'

Source: mscorlib

   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Web.Sprites.SpriteDefinitionManager..ctor(Database database, ID spriteStorageNodeId, ISpriteDefinitionFactory spriteDefinitionFactory, ICachedItemsWatcherFactory cachedItemsWatcherFactory)

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.PrepareEditorResources.Processors.RenderHiddenCachedImages.Process(PrepareEditorResourcesArgs args)

   at (Object , Object )

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.PrepareEditorResources.ExecutePrepareEditorResourcesPipeline.Run(PrepareEditorResourcesArgs args)

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.PageEditBar.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)

   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render()

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.ControlsExtension.PageEditBar(Controls controls, Rendering rendering, HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper)

   at ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_ExperienceEditor_PageEditbar_PageEditBar_cshtml.Execute() in d:\home\site\wwwroot\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\PageEditbar\PageEditBar.cshtml:line 4

   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()

   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()

   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)









2018-11-09T22:54:05  PID[1052] Error       11772 22:54:05 ERROR Application error.

Exception: System.Web.HttpUnhandledException

Message: An unhandled exception occurred.

Source: Sitecore.Mvc

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.ShowErrorMessage(ExceptionContext exceptionContext, ExceptionArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.MvcEvents.Exception.ShowAspNetErrorMessage.Process(ExceptionArgs args)

   at (Object , Object )

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Filters.PipelineBasedRequestFilter.OnException(ExceptionContext exceptionContext)

   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Routing.RouteHttpHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)

   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)



Nested Exception



Exception: System.InvalidOperationException

Message: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-Layout.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').



Source: Sitecore.Mvc

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)

   at (Object , Object )

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)

   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)

   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)

   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)

   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)

   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult)



Nested Exception



Exception: System.InvalidOperationException

Message: Error while rendering view: '/sitecore/shell/client/Sitecore/ExperienceEditor/PageEditbar/PageEditBar.cshtml' (model: 'Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.RenderingModel, Sitecore.Mvc').



Source: Sitecore.Mvc

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Render(Renderer renderer, TextWriter writer, RenderRenderingArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderRendering.ExecuteRenderer.Process(RenderRenderingArgs args)

   at (Object , Object )

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Response.RenderPlaceholder.PerformRendering.Render(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer, RenderPlaceholderArgs args)

   at (Object , Object )

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.PipelineService.RunPipeline[TArgs](String pipelineName, TArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.RenderPlaceholderCore(String placeholderName, TextWriter writer)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Helpers.SitecoreHelper.Placeholder(String placeholderName)

   at ASP._sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_Layout_cshtml.Execute()

   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()

   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()

   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)



Nested Exception



Exception: System.ArgumentException

Message: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '{B11432AF-89DD-4F53-A1A5-2A9D1B2244E0}'  Key being added: '{B11432AF-89DD-4F53-A1A5-2A9D1B2244E0}'

Source: mscorlib

   at System.Collections.Hashtable.Insert(Object key, Object nvalue, Boolean add)

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Web.Sprites.SpriteDefinitionManager..ctor(Database database, ID spriteStorageNodeId, ISpriteDefinitionFactory spriteDefinitionFactory, ICachedItemsWatcherFactory cachedItemsWatcherFactory)

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.PrepareEditorResources.Processors.RenderHiddenCachedImages.Process(PrepareEditorResourcesArgs args)

   at (Object , Object )

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain, Boolean failIfNotExists)

   at Sitecore.Pipelines.DefaultCorePipelineManager.Run(String pipelineName, PipelineArgs args, String pipelineDomain)

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.PrepareEditorResources.ExecutePrepareEditorResourcesPipeline.Run(PrepareEditorResourcesArgs args)

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.PageEditBar.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)

   at Sitecore.Web.UI.Controls.ComponentBase.Render()

   at Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Speak.PageEditbar.ControlsExtension.PageEditBar(Controls controls, Rendering rendering, HtmlHelper`1 htmlHelper)

   at ASP._Page_sitecore_shell_client_Sitecore_ExperienceEditor_PageEditbar_PageEditBar_cshtml.Execute() in d:\home\site\wwwroot\sitecore\shell\client\Sitecore\ExperienceEditor\PageEditbar\PageEditBar.cshtml:line 4

   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()

   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()

   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)

   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)

   at Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation.ViewRenderer.Render(TextWriter writer)
```

An interesting part of the error message is the mention of:

`Message: Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: '{B11432AF-89DD-4F53-A1A5-2A9D1B2244E0}'  Key being added: '{B11432AF-89DD-4F53-A1A5-2A9D1B2244E0}'`

This ID is an item in the core DB that corresponds to the following:

[image: Sprites item ID {B11432AF-89DD-4F53-A1A5-2A9D1B2244E0}]

It appears to me that this is a Sitecore bug. Any thoughts are appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this issue?

Comment: @DanSinclair I have not. Since then I have worked on completely different projects. The one I'm currently working on has no such exceptions being thrown and it still suffers from such behaviour. That is to say that I don't believe this specific exception is the cause of the 500 error. My suspicion is that this is a Sitecore issue that is exacerbated by Azure App Service deployments. To this day, VPS deployments don't suffer nearly as many performance issues. The primary advice we're given is to scale up the resources, but many clients do not have the budget to do so.